# How to get New vs Returning users in GA4

Tags: php, google-data-api, google-analytics-4

I have some of the sites using GA4 property and want to show the same reports which I was able to generate using UA property and Google analytics V3, But stuck on some of the metrics like new vs returning.
Any hints ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have more details and/or examples?

Comment: Actually I need to show data for how many new users have visited site and how many revisited. But as per dimension and metrics available in new GA4 data api userTypes is missing which was available in previous GA property data api.